# send keys entering previous rows value with new value in text box

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I have an excel with 100 rows of data (data only in column 1). I read it using XSSF classes. I need to read the value from each row and enter in text box of webpage to search for records.  However when script reads row3 and enter the value in text box, it also appends the value of row2 to value of row3. I just want current row value to enter in text box. I am not sure what am I missing here. Advise appreciated.

This is what i am trying to do

```
    File file = new File("file path");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    XSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheet(0);
    int rowCount=sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();

    for(int i=0;i<=rowCount;i++){
            String value = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            searchtxtbox.clear();
            searchtxtbox.sendKeys(value);

    }
}
```

I have tried javascript executor and that also didnt work as it disables the search icon next to search text box

Note : Using selenium webdriver with Java

Comment: Are you sure about issue is with sendKeys? While debugging are you seeing value variable is having unique value?

Comment: Add `searchtxtbox.click();` before `searchtxtbox.clear();`, maybe even with `Thread.sleep(1000);`.